# What does exec(Path('C:/PROGRA~1/KMSpico/temp/tmpq2wwvz7_.py').read_text()) mean?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, dxf

When I run this code:

```py
#Load the dfx file to get the sublayers.
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(dfx_file, 'layer_test', 'ogr')
subLayers = vlayer.dataProvider().subLayers()

#For each sublayer, different types of geometry, load a layer to map.
for subLayer in subLayers:
    #Extract the geometry type
    geom_type = subLayer.split(':')[-1]
    #Set the path
    uri = "%s|layername=entities|geometrytype=%s" % (dfx_file, geom_type)
    #Name for sub-layer
    dfx_file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(dfx_file))[0]
    layer_name = "%s - %s" % (dfx_file_name, geom_type)
    #Create layer
    sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, layer_name, 'ogr')
    #Add layer to map
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(sub_vlayer)
```

I receive this message:

```py
exec(Path('C:/PROGRA~1/KMSpico/temp/tmpq2wwvz7_.py').read_text())
```

What does this message mean?

[image]

Comment: i found it here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136686/loading-dxf-file-as-vector-layer-using-pyqgis

Comment: Usually the `program files` folder is writable only by admins, and for a good reason. You may want to revisit your windows configuration about the default `temp` folder, as well as the privileges that are currently set on these folders. Needless to say, I would be over-concerned when a security flaw is found with a software such as KMSPico - or a hacked copy of it -

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Because you haven't saved that script, QGIS is writing that code to a temporary file. QGIS then:

- Reads that temporary file containing your code as text: [`Path.read_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text)
- Executes the text read from the temporary file as python code: [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

If you save that script somewhere, the message will then read:

```
exec(Path('P:/ath/to/where/you/saved.py').read_text())
```

Comment: why the code doesn't display the layers in dxf separated in qgis?

Comment: That wasn't your question. Your question was what does `exec(Path('C:/PROGRA~1/KMSpico/temp/tmpq2wwvz7_.py').read_text())` mean. And both answers address that exactly.

Answer (score 5):

When you run an unsaved script in QGIS Python Editor, QGIS saves it as a temporary file, reads the file using `read_text()` and runs that temporary py file using `exec` function of Python. In your case, that file is `'C:/PROGRA~1/KMSpico/temp/tmpq2wwvz7_.py'`.

When you run it right after you save the script, QGIS runs the actual file (`/PATH/TO/Sans titre 0.py`).

If you edit the script again, and run the script without saving it, you get another temporary file name.

Comment: I don't want it to be executed as text; is there a solution for the code to display the layers in dxf separated in qgis?

Comment: @Student if you don't want that code executed, then don't run it.  Both answers address your question about what `exec(Path('C:/PROGRA~1/KMSpico/temp/tmpq2wwvz7_.py').read_text())` means. You did not ask about why nothing is displayed, which you have asked in a [different question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/450604/2856).